# ERR_EMPTY_RESPONE puppeteer-extra

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

Why always "ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE" when using puppeteer-extra? I've tried not to use the stealth plugin, not to use a proxy, and also not to change the user agent but still error.

This my code

```js
(async () => {
    for (let i = 0; i < proxy.length; i++) {
        for (let p = 0; p < 3; p++) {
            const browser = await puppeteer.launch(cfg);
            const page = await browser.newPage();
            const userAgent = new UserAgent(/*{
                platform: "MacIntel",
                deviceCategory: "desktop",
            }*/);

            const userAgentStr = userAgent.toString();
            console.log(`User Agent: ${userAgentStr}`);

            const anonymizeUserAgentPlugin =
                require("puppeteer-extra-plugin-anonymize-ua")({
                    customFn: () => userAgentStr,
                    stripHeadless: true,
                    makeWindows: false,
                });

            puppeteer.use(anonymizeUserAgentPlugin);
            await page.goto("https://discord.com/register");
            const data = await dc.register(page);
            console.log(data);
            accounts.write(data + "\n\n<====================>\n\n");
            await browser.close();
        }
    }
})();
```

Any solution to fix "ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE" error?